# optimal solution for producer consumer

Tags: java, producer-consumer

I have written code for producer consumer problem. Below is the code

```
package sample;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Interview2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        Thread producer = new Thread(new Producer(empList , 4) , "Producer");
        Thread consumer = new Thread(new Consumer(empList , 4) , "Consumer");

        producer.start();
        consumer.start();
    }

}

class Employee 
{
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
class Producer implements Runnable 
{
    List<Employee> empList; 
    int size;

    public Producer(final List<Employee> empList  , final int size)
    {
        this.empList = empList;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public void run() {
        for(int i=0; i<7;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Produced "+i);
            try {
                produce(new Employee());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }

public void produce(Employee e) throws InterruptedException
{
    while(empList.size()==size) // If list is full then will have to wait
    {
        synchronized(empList)
        {
            System.out.println("List is full "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Is waiting and" + " Size is "+empList.size());
            empList.wait();
        }
    }

    synchronized(empList)
    {
        empList.add(e);
        empList.notify();
    }
}


}


class Consumer implements Runnable 
{
    List<Employee> empList; 
    int size;

    public Consumer(final List<Employee> empList  , final int size)
    {
        this.empList = empList;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try {
                System.out.println("Consumed ");
                Thread.sleep(50);
                consume();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void consume() throws InterruptedException
    {
        while(empList.isEmpty()) // If list is empty then will have to wait
        {
            synchronized(empList)
            {
                System.out.println("List is empty "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Is waiting and " + "Size is "+empList.size());
                empList.wait();
            }
        }

        synchronized(empList)
        {
            empList.remove(0);
            empList.notifyAll();
        }

    }

}
```

But I want this code to be like producer adds one employee in list after that consumer consumes it means there must be switch between producer and consumer. I want to repeat it for 10 objects. Kindly help me to modify the code. Thanks in advance

Comment: Note: `empList.size()==size` needs to be within the `synchronized` block otherwise it could return a stale value. But ArrayLists are not well suited for what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: @assylias could u please explain me in which case it can give me stale value??

Comment: ArrayList is not thread safe, so calling *any* of its methods without proper synchronization is not guaranteed to return consistent results. Using a thread safe collection, in your case a BlockingQueue is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this looks like some kind of an assignment, I am going to point you in the right direction instead of providing the code itself :

You can use an [ArrayBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) with size 1 instead of an `ArrayList` :

```
ArrayBlockingQueue<Employee> empList = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Employee>(1);
```

The `ArrayBlockingQueue` class provides two blocking calls namely [put](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#put(E)) and [take](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#take()). By using these methods, you can get rid of any explicit thread communication that you are currently doing through `wait` and `notify`. The ideal way to do this would be to call the `put` method in your `Producer` thread and the `take` method in your `Consumer` thread in a `while` loop.

Since the queue is initialized with a size of 1, any thread that tries to insert a new element in the queue when it is full will wait when `put` is called in the while loop. Similarly, any thread trying to get an element from the queue when it is empty will have to wait when `take` is called in the while loop.

Comment: @assylias  In my above program after the execution of producer's run method consumer thread keeps on waiting in indefinite loop. How can I ensure that after producer thread has ended and consumer thread has consumed all the elements , it must finish ??... please help me with code

Comment: @rishi I think you meant to tag me in the comment. You need to use a variable that keeps a track of the number of elements read from the queue and decrement it every time you call `take`